# MariaDB populating a JSON column with data from other columns

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I try this in a MariaDB Procedure:

```
DECLARE InstrumentCounter int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE JSON_Data json; 
SET InstrumentCounter = 0;
  SET Counter = 0;    
WHILE Counter < 100 DO 
    WHILE InstrumentCounter < 8 DO
        SET @finalQuery =  
        CONCAT("
            SELECT sc.idInstrument",InstrumentCounter,"
            INTO
            @ID
            FROM ",DataBaseToModify,".service_call sc 
            LIMIT ",Counter,",1;
        "); /*  LIMIT Counter,1 is what makes it go row by row */
        
        SELECT JSON_OBJECT('ID',@ID) 
        INTO 
        @data_json;
      /* */
      PREPARE stmt FROM @finalQuery;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      /* */
      SET InstrumentCounter = InstrumentCounter + 1;
      SELECT JSON_Data;
      /* */
    END WHILE; 
    SET Counter = Counter + 1; 
    END WHILE;
```

MariaDB throws the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
> 'ID',@ID at line xx

However, if I remove the query from the While Do Loop. Like this:

```
SELECT sc.idInstrument0
INTO
@ID
FROM service_call sc 
LIMIT 0,1;

SELECT JSON_OBJECT('ID',@ID) 
INTO 
@data_json;
```

It works. So, I believe the Concat() is preventing MariaDB from working with the string. How do I go about to be able to loop using concat in this scenario?

**How do I make the @ID be visible to MariaDB Procedure when using Concat)?**

Comment: it would be nice if the question is in [mcve] format with less noises. its kinda hard to navigate around, really.

Comment: Let me simplify it.

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and they are not fully compatible. In particular, their implementations of JSON functions is not compatible. Since your syntax error mentions MariaDB, it's clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. I've edited your text and tags to make this more clear.

Comment: err, am i seeing it right that your `select json_object(...` is well outside the `concat(...` while it require `@ID` from the query inside the `concat(...`?

Comment: Its the `EXECUTE stmt` (see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) it doesn't need a prepare or *release*) that will transform the concat string into a statement that populates `@ID`, and this is *after* your `select json_object ..`. Reorder those statements. Better, use a CURSOR to iterate a query rather than limit/offset. Better still again, show sample data and desired output and maybe there's a better way, [json_objectagg](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/) for example.